# What does Technical Constraint and Organisational Constraint mean in terms of Internet Security Management

Tags: governance

I am on an essay with regards to the following topic:

> Information security management involves challenges that are
>   essentially unique due to the combination of technical and
>   organisational constraints. Identify two such challenges and discuss
>   in depth how these can affect the way information security management
>   is performed within an organisation.

I am uncertain of the items that I will need to include.

May I request for some examples of technical and organisational constraints?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A technical limitation could be lack of processing power to perform a specific task, for example if you work for Yahoo Mail and you can't digitally sign every email then this can be seen as a technical limitation.

An organisational limitation could be not being able to use smart cards because the company culture does not allow such an authentication mechanism